# sql Not Able Display the only string values in starting values of the column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have  a table called tbl_temp it has column like ID BIGINT(20),sample_no VARCHAR(100) the problem is i need to display the values of a column named sample_no NOT STARTING from ZX and sample_no starting value will not start from numeric value.

After lot of research i have found this solution.

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_temp`
WHERE sample_no > '' AND sample_no NOT LIKE 'ZX%'
AND  sample_no NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

But it still displays the column named sample_no values starting from numeric.
Any Solutions?

Comment: strip of 1st '%' in last like and reverse it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_temp`
WHERE sample_no > '' 
AND sample_no NOT LIKE 'ZX%'
AND sample_no LIKE '[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: Still not working i do not want to display sample_no value starting from numeric. May be it is VARCHAR(100) column type???

Comment: with `AND sample_no LIKE '[^0-9]%'` sample_no starting with a number are excluded. post you sample data...

Comment: sample_no 16265310

Comment: try `select 'ok' where 16265310 LIKE '[^0-9]%'` if you do not see OK, the query is working

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for my problem.

SELECT *
FROM `tbl_temp`
WHERE sample_no NOT LIKE 'ZX%'
AND sample_no NOT LIKE '1%'
AND sample_no NOT LIKE 's%'
AND sample_no IS NOT NULL and sample_no !=''